# Android save data to firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try save something to firebase Database from android.

I create DB in firebase, and connect project to firebase in android studio, as you can see on screenshot 
[image: connection to firebase from android studio]
I type this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

In firebase I set rules:
For cloud:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/** {
allow read, write  }}
```

For realtime:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
}
}
```

And nothing happens. I don't see "Hello, World!" in firebase console, I don't see ane warning and errors in android logcat. What I do wrong?

Comment: Since you're writing to the Firebase Realtime Database, the first set of rules you shared is meaningless (as is the `google-cloud-firestore` tag). I don't immediately see what's going wrong, but I highly recommend minimizing the scope of your question to maximize the changes someone can help.

Comment: In your Firebase project, check realtimedatabase to see anything is written or not.

Comment: May I know if you put the google json inside your apps?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a firebase realtime database bug. It happens when you not select USA server (beta). And occures with no errors or warning of any kind.

Use direct link from firebase console in `getInstance()` (change xxx with your project data from firebase console realtime database section)
[image: firebase]

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebasedatabase.app/")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//firebase console official link
https://console.firebase.google.com

//setup your project into firebase console
//add dependency to  build.gradle(Module:app) file

 dependencies{
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
}

// reference of firebase official docs for dependency
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

//tutorial link (youtube)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71H9-MRXYOE
```